# Problems Exporting FBX from Blender?

Tags: modeling, armature, weight-painting, unreal-engine

Hello I have been having some problems exporting my fbx model from blender to unreal. In blender there are no issues, but when I import it into unreal, the front part of the mesh is extruding.

[image: Blender Image]
[image: UE4 Image]

Any Suggestions? Thanks for reading this!

Comment: Is it possible you did not apply scale/rotation/position to the model and that is messing something up?

Comment: it would be very helpful if you could upload your blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for examination

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

- apply all modifiers before exporting
- apply rotation location and scale (ctrl+a)
- Check your export options in Blender
- When importing in UE4, import the skeleton first and then the skeletal mesh

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those vertices have not received any weights at all yet? You can check that by going to vertex select in Edit Mode, and then choose **Select by Trait** --> **Ungrouped Vertices** from the menu:

[image: trait vertices]

If that does select vertices, those are not weighted at all yet and could cause artifacting later on. Add them to the vertex groups they should belong to and try again to export.